# JavaScript only works in debug mode with a break

Tags: javascript

I have JavaScript code that is supposed to add input boxes to my html and then save the user input into and array.  When I run my code regularly the screen refreshes and nothing happens.  If I run it a second time it works how it should.  Similarly if I open up debug mode and put a break point in the code works just fine the first time I try to run it.  Is there an asynchronous issue I'm not aware of?

Also the event listener is checking for when someone hits the enter key on the web page otherwise the code doesn't execute.

Also, I'm new to stack overflow I've found the help so far great and if I'm not doing something in proper etiquette of asking a question please let me know!

```
var recipients = document.getElementById("howMany");
recipients.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        validate(e);
    }
})

 function validate(e) {
    var num2 = document.getElementById("howMany");
    num2 = document.getElementById("howMany").value;
    var values = new Array();
  for (i = 1; i < num2; i++){
                    //loop set to repeat to the amount of guests inputed by user
                    container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Recipient " + (i+1)+":"));
                        //creates a text for the user to read which recipient each input is for
                    var x = document.createElement("input");
                        //creates the input element
                    x.setAttribute("id", "empInput"+i);
                    x.setAttribute("type", "text");
                    x.setAttribute("value", "");
                        //sets the type and attribute
                    container.appendChild(x);
                        //places the input element in the container
                    values[i] = document.getElementById("empInput"+i).value;

        } 

    //console.log(values);
 }
```

Comment: I don't know where this code is within your html, but if the script executes before the `howMany` element is finished loading, your initial `getElementById` may fail.  Best to execute from within an `onpageload` event.

Comment: The setTimeout smells funny. Why are you using it?

Comment: I removed the setTimeout I thought maybe the DOM needed to load first.

Comment: It will be helpful if you post the `html` too

Comment: If it's a form, Enter key is used to submit it, just add `e.preventDefault();` inside `if` to avoid form submission.